# how to change background color of parent component dynamically from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with a T-shirt design app using fabric.js in reactjs. I am facing some problem when I wanna change the t shirt color. What I want to do is change T-shirt color from child component but failed to pass data. How can I do this?
Child and parent components has been given:

**Parent component**

```
export default function Home() {
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState('');
  const initCanvas = () => (
    new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
      height: 540,
      width: 445,
      backgroundColor: "Green",
      backgroundImage: "/assets/background_tshirt.png",
    }));
  useEffect(() => {
    setCanvas(initCanvas());
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
    <div>
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
    <Stickers design = {canvas}></Stickers>
    <Colors></Colors>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Child component**

```
export default function Colors(){
    const [value] = useState('');
    return(
        <div>
            <div>
            <label for="tshirt-color">T-Shirt Color:</label>
            <select value={value} onChange={(canvi)=>{
                console.log(canvi.target.value)
            }} id="tshirt-color">
            <option value="#fff">White</option>
            <option value="#000">Black</option>
            <option value="#f00">Red</option>
            <option value="#008000">Green</option>
            <option value="#ff0">Yellow</option>
        </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in the parent component and pass that function as props to child component. Call that function when select is change and pass the value as argument to function

Comment: problem solved but getting "Object render is not a function". Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: share code pls it looks like you are rendering something which is not a function/component

Comment: I have shared my code

Comment: I figured out the problem. The problem with the background color of Canvas. When I put a background color i will get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my index.js code:

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric'
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Stickers from '../components/stickers/stickers'
import Colors from '../components/stickers/colors/colors'

function Home(){
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState('');
  const backgroundColor = useState(false);
  const initCanvas=()=>(
    new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
      height: 540,
      width: 445,
      backgroundColor:"",
      backgroundImage:"/assets/background_tshirt.png",
      allowTouchScrolling: true
    }));
  const sendcolorToParent=(color)=>{
    let addColor = color
    console.log(addColor)
    setCanvas(
      new fabric.StaticCanvas('canvas',{
        height: 540,
        width: 445,
        backgroundColor: addColor,
        backgroundImage: "/assets/background_tshirt.png",
        allowTouchScrolling: true,
      })
      
    );
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    setCanvas(initCanvas());
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
    <div>
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
    <Stickers design = {canvas}></Stickers>
    <Colors sendcolorToParent={sendcolorToParent}></Colors>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default Home;
```

And here is colors.js

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Home from "../../../pages";

function Colors({sendcolorToParent}){
    const [value,setValue,setCanvas] = useState('')
    const setState = useState(0);
    return(
        <div>
            <div>
            <label htmlFor="tshirt-color">T-Shirt Color:</label>
            <select value={value} onChange={(canvas)=>setValue(
                sendcolorToParent(canvas.target.value),
            )} id="tshirt-color">
            <option value="#fff">White</option>
            <option value="#000">Black</option>
            <option value="#f00">Red</option>
            <option value="#008000">Green</option>
            <option value="#ff0">Yellow</option>
        </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Colors;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).